# Do we need to worry about weak self inside methods called from closures

Tags: swift

Trivial but looking for confirmation I'm understanding correctly:

If we have a simple closure as so:

```
let closure = { [weak self] in 
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

Do we need to worry about weak/strong self within the method itself?

```
func doSomething() {
    self.classString = "some new string" 
    // the self in this case will come from the weak self in the closure?
}
```

The following as I understand is unnecessary even though it'll be called from a closure:

```
func doSomething() {
    weak var weakSelf = self
    weakSelf.classString = "some new string" 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we don't need to worry because a method is not capturing anything.